# Draftsight "failed to load modules"

Tags: 14.04

I'm working on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit, before I was using 14.04 LTS.

When I installed Draftsight with (Gdebi) every time I want to start Draftsight I get this message:

```
Failed to load modules . the application will close please reinstall the application
```

NOTE: it was working well on the 14.04.

I tried to reinstall it and I got the same message.

I tried to install i386 files and also no new result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem for draftsight 2016 Sp1 in Ubuntu 16.04 and solved by install gstreamer0.10-x after I read this:

> [qwerty1417235 commented on 2015-08-30 06:26](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/draftsight/?comments=all#comment-510398):
>
> @Crispy24 installing gstreamer0.10-base instead of gstreamer0.10 and gstreamer0.10-plugins is ok. You should add it to depends.